# What is the difference between these two ways of declaring a map in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript I can delcare a map like this:

```
{[key:number]string}
```

As an example of a map whose keys are numbers and values string. But I can also do it like this:

```
Map<number, string>
```

Why do we have two ways to do the same and what is the difference among them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is a native JS object that holds pairs of keys and values. So you can do:

```
let myMap = new Map();
myMap.set('bla','blaa');
myMap.set('bla2','blaa2');
```

And that will create a map with those values.

Your other type, `{[key:number]: string}`, types an **object** that has the keys of type `number` and the values of type `string`. The main difference between a **map** and a **plain object** is a map's key can be anything (it doesn't have to be a string, number or Symbol unlike object) and it is also better optimized. [See the MDN documentation for a full list of differences.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_vs._Maps)